# How to validate particular row in a table using ROBOT framework?

Tags: selenium, validation, user-interface, robotframework, webautomation

Here, I add one device and need to validate that one.
How to validate particular 2nd row in a table using ROBOT framework
[image]

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SeleniumLibrary to test your WebApp:

**1. First solution:**
Use "Table Cell Should Contain" keyword
[[Documentation]](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Table%20Cell%20Should%20Contain)

**2. Second solution:**

-You need is to get all the elements of second row, something like:

```
${data}   Get WebElements   id=//"id for all elements in second row"
```

-Then with that you can run a for cycle to check each element:

```
FOR   ${element}   in   @{data}
   ${data}   Get Text   ${element}
   your test..
END
```

Answer (score 0):

suggest you try another automation library clicknium, similiar as selenium, but instead writing xpath or css-selector,you can define the tablerow or tablecolumn in recorded locator